# Message pumping?

Tags: winforms

In Winforms, there is a concept called "Message pumping". Is there an explanation of what all of this is, and why it's important?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you start here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff381409%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

This explains how the basics of how Windows works, and is directly from Microsoft.

I would suggest following through the hierarchy of links provided on that particular MSDN tutorial (follow the links marked "Next" at the bottom of the content on each page).

This link may be a more direct answer to your question:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff381405%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

If you really want to understand the inner workings of Windows, I would suggest obtaining a copy of this book:

Windows programming with C++ - ISBN-10: 0201758814

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_loop_in_Microsoft_Windows)?

> Microsoft Windows programs are event-based. They act upon messages that the operating system posts to the main thread of the application. These messages are received from the message queue by the application by repeatedly calling the GetMessage (or PeekMessage) function in a section of code called the "event loop."